# correlation between two data

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I wanted to find correlation between two terms;
Probability of abusive comments and Number of comments per post
where Probability of abusive comments is Abusive comments per post/Total comments per post.

My data contains instagram all posts of 50 users with their comments.

So I use the .corr() method (Pearson's correlation):
Both of these terms are not part of my column.
So I calculated probabability of every posts of every user. I will user corr method for my new table.
I am unable to verify is this correct approach to find correlation.

I will use then this code:

```
data = df[['Probability of abusive comments','Number of comments']]

correlation = data.corr(method='pearson')
```

Answer (score 1):

Without viewing sample input data it's a little tricky to understand what you're after. But the following should be able to be adapted to your data:

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'X' :    [1,4,5,6],
    'Y' :    [2,5,5,5],
})

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

correlation = df['X'].corr(df['Y'])
print(correlation) 

0.925820099773
```

Comment: So you need to achieve a few things before this becomes workable. Overall, you need to convert to numerical data. Number of comments should be easy enough. Just do a count of comments per post. _Abusive comments_ may be a little more tricky. You'll first have to determine what is and isn't _abusive_. This will be arbitrary but as long as you're consistent with categorising you'll be able to quantify your question.